# Material Dialog: los datos se modifican en el modal y en el formulario origen a la vez

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema. Cuando le doy al botón de editar para editar un registro, se desplega modal: cuando modifico por ejemplo el campo "edad" o "nombre_autor" se modifica a la vez en el modal "formeditar.component.html" y en la vista del "tabla.component.html". No entiendo la razón.

"formeditar.component.ts":

```html
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiciocrudService } from '../../servicio/serviciocrud.service';

import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Autor } from '../../modelos/autor/autor.module';

import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FormComponent } from '../form/form.component';
import { FomreditarComponent } from '../fomreditar/fomreditar.component';



export interface Shirt { nombre_autor: string; edad: number}
export interface ShirtId extends Shirt { id: string; }


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tablacrud',
  templateUrl: './tablacrud.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tablacrud.component.css']
})
export class TablacrudComponent implements OnInit {

  columnas: string[] = ['edad','nombre_autor','acciones'];
  autores: ShirtId[] ;
  dataSource = null;
  regreso: any;


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private miservicio: ServiciocrudService, private dialog: MatDialog ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {


    this.miservicio.retornar2().subscribe( data => {

      this.autores = data;

      console.log(this.autores);

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ShirtId>(this.autores);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      
    });  
    
    
  }
    onDelete(id)
    {
      console.log("borramos", id);
      //console.log("borramos")
      this.miservicio.borrarAutor(id);

    }

    
    onEdit(elemento: ShirtId)
    {   console.log("imprimimos en el onEdit de tablacrud ");
        console.log("ID " + elemento.id);
        console.log("edad " + elemento.edad);
        console.log("nombre_autor " + elemento.nombre_autor);
      let nuevovalor =elemento; 
      this.openModalEditar(nuevovalor);
    }

    openModalEditar(valor: ShirtId)
    {
      
      const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
      dialogConfig.data = valor;

      dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
      
      this.dialog.open(FomreditarComponent,dialogConfig);
      
    }


  
    onCreate()
    {
      this.openModalCrear();
    }

    openModalCrear()
    {
      const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
      dialogConfig.data = {
        edad: null,
        nombre_autor: ''
      };

      dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
      
      this.dialog.open(FormComponent,dialogConfig);
    }

    resetearFormulario(){
      this.miservicio.seleccionado.edad = null;
      this.miservicio.seleccionado.nombre_autor="";

    }

    
    
}
```

Código del "tablacrud.component.ts":

```html
<p>tablacrud works!</p>

<div>
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="onCreate()">
        <mat-icon>save</mat-icon>NUEVO
    </button>
</div>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" #tabla1 style="width: 100%">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="edad">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EDAD </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let articulo"> {{articulo.edad}} </td>

        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre_autor">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> nombre </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let articulo"> {{articulo.nombre_autor}} </td>

        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="acciones">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> acciones </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let articulo">
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" background-color="green" (click)="onEdit(articulo)">EDITAR</button>
                <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onDelete(articulo.id)">BORRAR</button>
            </td>
        </ng-container>


        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas;"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

</div>
```

Y el modal desplegable "formeditar.component.ts":

```html
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { ServiciocrudService } from '../../servicio/serviciocrud.service';
import { ShirtId } from '../tablacrud/tablacrud.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fomreditar',
  templateUrl: './fomreditar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fomreditar.component.css']
})
export class FomreditarComponent implements OnInit {

  

  constructor(
    public servicio: ServiciocrudService,
    private dialogolo:  MatDialogRef<FomreditarComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log("imprimimos en el onInit del foprmulario");
    console.log("id: "+ this.data.id);
    console.log("edad: "+ this.data.edad);
    console.log("nombre_autor: " + this.data.nombre_autor);
  }

  editarAutor(data: ShirtId)
  {
    this.servicio.editarAutor(data);
  }
```

la vista del modal "formeditar.component.html":

```html
<div>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Edad" [(ngModel)]="data.edad">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="nombre_autor" [(ngModel)]="data.nombre_autor">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="guardarAutor(data) ">
        <mat-icon>save</mat-icon>Save
    </button>
</div>
```

Desde "tablacrud.component.html" llamamos a la función "onEdit(articulo)" de su archivo ts. Luego abrimos el modal "formularioeditar.component.html" pero si modifico un campo de este modal se modifica también en "tablacrud.component.ts"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es por que cuando asignas un objeto a una variable `(let nuevovalor =elemento)` , estas apuntando a memoria, por lo tanto si modificas esa variable también se modifica el objeto original.

Cambia lo siguiente.

```
let nuevovalor =elemento;
```

por:

```
let nuevovalor = Object.assign({}, elemento);
```

Así creamos una copia del objeto original.

Comment: Es decir, al hacer "let nuevovalor =elemento;" tanto "nuevovalor" como "elemento" apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria y tanto si cambias "nuevovalor" también cambias "elmento" y vivecersa? ... yo vengo de otros lenguajes donde no pasa esto (soy novato)

Comment: Sabes cómo se llama técnicamente a esta forma de compartir el mismo valor entre propiedades en Angular.? O un enlace de un tutorial para poder entenderlo bien.

Comment: Así es, se trata sobre la  **Mutabilidad de objetos** , dado que Angular esta en typescript y este es un superconjunto de JavaScript, basta con que busques [mutable javascript](https://gomakethings.com/mutable-vs.-immutable-in-javascript/)